# Convert dot syntax like "this.that.other" to multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, parsing

Just as the title implies, I am trying to create a parser and trying to find the optimal solution to convert something from dot namespace into a multidimensional array such that

```
s1.t1.column.1 = size:33%
```

would be the same as

```
$source['s1']['t1']['column']['1'] = 'size:33%';
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to rewrite the PHP syntax.

Comment: I'm writing a markup language and chose to parse it with PHP.

Comment: I don't think this question duplicate or response linked it's for this question.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Try this number...

```
function assignArrayByPath(&$arr, $path, $value, $separator='.') {
    $keys = explode($separator, $path);

    foreach ($keys as $key) {
        $arr = &$arr[$key];
    }

    $arr = $value;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/j9nFiTiZ)

It will loop through the keys (delimited with `.` by default) to get to the final property, and then do assignment on the value.

If some of the keys aren't present, they're created.

Comment: for the record, this would be the complementary variant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10424516/1388892

Comment: There is a bug in this function. 
Because of the "while" evaluation, if there is a 0 in the path it will break the cycle:

abc.0.bac.1

Will produce:
$arr['abc'] only.

To fix, just replace the first line with while () ... to a foreach cycle.

Also, adding a forth parameter $separator to it will make it much more useful for different cases (e.g. when you have underscore or dashes):

function assignArrayByPath(&$arr, $path, $value, $separator='.') {
        $keys = explode($separator, $path);
        foreach($keys AS $key) {
            $arr = &$arr[$key];
        }
        $arr = $value;
}

Comment: @PavelBogatinov Agree on those points, I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 38):

FYI In Laravel we have a `array_set()` helper function which translates in this function

### Method to store in an array using dot notation

```php
/**
 * Set an array item to a given value using "dot" notation.
 *
 * If no key is given to the method, the entire array will be replaced.
 *
 * @param  array   $array
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $value
 * @return array
 */
public static function set(&$array, $key, $value)
{
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $array = $value;
    }

    $keys = explode('.', $key);

    while (count($keys) > 1) {
        $key = array_shift($keys);

        // If the key doesn't exist at this depth, we will just create an empty array
        // to hold the next value, allowing us to create the arrays to hold final
        // values at the correct depth. Then we'll keep digging into the array.
        if (! isset($array[$key]) || ! is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = [];
        }

        $array = &$array[$key];
    }

    $array[array_shift($keys)] = $value;

    return $array;
}
```

It's simple as

```php
$array = ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 100]]];

array_set($array, 'products.desk.price', 200);

// ['products' => ['desk' => ['price' => 200]]]
```

You may check it [in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-array-set)

**If you need to instead get the data using dot notation** the process is a bit longer, but served on a plate by `array_get()` which translates to [this function](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Arr.php#L270-L305) (actually the linked source shows you all the helper array related class)

### Method to read from an an array using dot notation

```php
/**
 * Get an item from an array using "dot" notation.
 *
 * @param  \ArrayAccess|array  $array
 * @param  string  $key
 * @param  mixed   $default
 * @return mixed
 */
public static function get($array, $key, $default = null)
{
    if (! static::accessible($array)) {
        return value($default);
    }
    if (is_null($key)) {
        return $array;
    }
    if (static::exists($array, $key)) {
        return $array[$key];
    }
    if (strpos($key, '.') === false) {
        return $array[$key] ?? value($default);
    }
    foreach (explode('.', $key) as $segment) {
        if (static::accessible($array) && static::exists($array, $segment)) {
            $array = $array[$segment];
        } else {
            return value($default);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

As you can see, it uses two submethods, `accessible()` and `exists()`

```php
/**
 * Determine whether the given value is array accessible.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $value
 * @return bool
 */
public static function accessible($value)
{
    return is_array($value) || $value instanceof ArrayAccess;
}
```

And

```php
/**
 * Determine if the given key exists in the provided array.
 *
 * @param  \ArrayAccess|array  $array
 * @param  string|int  $key
 * @return bool
 */
public static function exists($array, $key)
{
    if ($array instanceof ArrayAccess) {
        return $array->offsetExists($key);
    }
    return array_key_exists($key, $array);
}
```

Last thing it uses, but you can probably skip that, is `value()` which is

```php
if (! function_exists('value')) {
    /**
     * Return the default value of the given value.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    function value($value)
    {
        return $value instanceof Closure ? $value() : $value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use this function to convert dot notation arrray to multidimensional array.

```php
function flattenToMultiDimensional(array $array, $delimiter = '.')
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $notations => $value) {
        // extract keys
        $keys = explode($delimiter, $notations);
        // reverse keys for assignments
        $keys = array_reverse($keys);

        // set initial value
        $lastVal = $value;
        foreach ($keys as $key) {
            // wrap value with key over each iteration
            $lastVal = [
                $key => $lastVal
            ];
        }
        
        // merge result
        $result = array_merge_recursive($result, $lastVal);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Example:

```php
$array = [
    'test.example.key' => 'value'
];

print_r(flattenToMultiDimensional($array));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [example] => Array
                (
                    [key] => value
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [dflydev/dot-access-data](https://packagist.org/packages/dflydev/dot-access-data).

If you're not familiar with using Composer, head over to https://getcomposer.org/ for an introduction so that you can download and autoload the package as as dependency for your project.

Once you have the package, you can load a multi-dimensional array into a Data object:

```
use Dflydev\DotAccessData\Data;

$data = new Data(array(
  's1' => array(
    't1' => array(
      'column' => array(
        '1' => 'size:33%',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

And access the values using dot notation:

```
$size = $username = $data->get('s1.t1.column.1');
```

Comment: This doesn't explain converting an array of dot notation to a multidimensional array. This is the other way around

Answer (score 0):

After more than a decade nobody has actually answered the question of converting string *x* to array *y*. The accepted answer came closest, but still assumes an existing array and requires a separate value.

I needed to do just this in a quick one-off script, so my answer does what the question asked, while allowing some customization of separators, and basic error checking:

```php
<?php
function dotKvToArray(string $kv, string $kv_sep = "=", string $arr_sep = "."): array
{
    // split on the equal sign (if it's there)
    [$keystring, $value] = str_contains($kv, $kv_sep)
        ? explode($kv_sep, $kv, 2)
        : [$kv, ""];

    // return early for empty string
    if (trim($keystring) === "") {
        return [];
    }

    // reverse the array keys and assign the array to each sequentially
    // the first one will get the value assigned instead
    foreach (array_reverse(explode($arr_sep, trim($keystring))) as $key) {
        $ret = [$key => $ret ?? trim($value)];
    }

    // return the array, or an empty array in case somehow the loop was missed
    return $ret ?? [];
}

$source = dotKvToArray("s1.t1.column.1 = size:33%");
echo json_encode($source);
```

Output:

```json
{"s1":{"t1":{"column":{"1":"size:33%"}}}}
```

Comment: The ternary expression and the  typing on `$kv` in the function signature ensure that `$keystring` is always defined and always a string. Though I wasn’t using numeric keys, getting rid of `empty()` is probably a good idea anyway since “0” is falsy.

Answer (score -2):

Although pasrse_ini_file() can also bring out multidimensional array, I will present a different solution. **[Zend_Config_Ini()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html)**

```
$conf = new Zend_COnfig_Ini("path/to/file.ini");
echo $conf -> one -> two -> three; // This is how easy it is to do so
//prints one.two.three
```

Answer (score -3):

I found a solution that worked for me at: [Convert Flat PHP Array to Nested Array based on Array Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116796/convert-flat-php-array-to-nested-array-based-on-array-keys/7116957#7116957) and since I had an array based on an .ini file with different keys I made a tiny [modification of that script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7116796/convert-flat-php-array-to-nested-array-based-on-array-keys/38480572#38480572) and made work for me.

My array looked like this:

```
[resources.db.adapter] => PDO_MYSQL
[resources.db.params.host] => localhost
[resources.db.params.dbname] => qwer
[resources.db.params.username] => asdf
...
```

**On request, this is the code that I described was working for me:**

```
<?php
echo "remove the exit :-)"; exit;
$db_settings = parse_ini_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/website/var/config/app.ini');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($db_settings);
echo "</pre>";

$resources = array();

foreach ($db_settings as $path => $value) {
  $ancestors = explode('.', $path);
  set_nested_value($resources, $ancestors, $value);
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($resources);
echo "</pre>";

/**
 * Give it and array, and an array of parents, it will decent into the
 * nested arrays and set the value.
 */
function set_nested_value(array &$arr, array $ancestors, $value) {
  $current = &$arr;
  foreach ($ancestors as $key) {

    // To handle the original input, if an item is not an array, 
    // replace it with an array with the value as the first item.
    if (!is_array($current)) {
      $current = array( $current);
    }

    if (!array_key_exists($key, $current)) {
      $current[$key] = array();
    }
    $current = &$current[$key];
  }

  $current = $value;
}
```

This is the source of the .ini file read by the parse_ini_file():

```
Array
(
    [resources.db.adapter] => PDO_MYSQL
    [resources.db.params.host] => localhost
    [resources.db.params.dbname] => dbname
    [resources.db.params.username] => dbname_user
    [resources.db.params.password] => qwerqwerqwerqwer
    [resources.db.params.charset] => utf8
    [externaldb.adapter] => PDO_MYSQL
    [externaldb.params.host] => localhost
    [externaldb.params.dbname] => dbname2
    [externaldb.params.username] => dbname_user2
    [externaldb.params.password] => qwerqwerwqerqerw
    [externaldb.params.charset] => latin1
)
```

This is the outcome of the code above:

```
Array
(
    [resources] => Array
        (
            [db] => Array
                (
                    [adapter] => PDO_MYSQL
                    [params] => Array
                        (
                            [host] => localhost
                            [dbname] => dbname
                            [username] => dbname_user
                            [password] => qwerqwerqwerqwer
                            [charset] => utf8
                        )

                )

        )

    [externaldb] => Array
        (
            [adapter] => PDO_MYSQL
            [params] => Array
                (
                    [host] => localhost
                    [dbname] => dbname2
                    [username] => dbname_user2
                    [password] => qwerqwerwqerqerw
                    [charset] => latin1
                )

        )
)
```

Answer (score -4):

I am pretty sure you are trying to do this to store some configuration data or similar.

I highly suggest you to save such file as `.ini` and use [parse_ini_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php) function to change the configuration data into a multidimensional array. As simple as this

```
$confArray = parse_ini_file("filename.ini"); 
var_dump($confArray);
```

Comment: Not quite.  I need the multi-dimensional index, which the ini parser does not do.

Answer (score -4):

Quick and dirty...

```
<?php

$input = 'one.two.three = four';

list($key, $value) = explode('=', $input);
foreach (explode('.', $key) as $keyName) {
    if (false === isset($source)) {
        $source    = array();
        $sourceRef = &$source;
    }
    $keyName = trim($keyName);
    $sourceRef  = &$sourceRef[$keyName];
}
$sourceRef = $value;
unset($sourceRef);
var_dump($source);
```

Comment: Agreed, but "quick and dirty" was the tagline ;)

Comment: This a good alternative solution. However, it can only assign a string.

Comment: @BryanPotts -you didn't see Pavel's code above I guess.