# Python array from set of keys

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, dictionary

I need to create array/dictionaries in python based on an array which contains keys.
I found an [equivalent solution in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765706/php-array-from-set-of-keys/15320688#15320688). Unfortunately I don't know how I can implement this in Python. Can somebdoy give me any tips?

```
a = ['one', 'two', 'three']
b = ['one', 'four', 'six']
```

I want to get the following result:

```
c = {'one': {'two': 'three', 'four': 'six}}
```

The PHP solution uses references for that. Perhaps this is a better example:

```
ar[0] = ['box0', 'border0', 'name']
var[1] = ['box0', 'border0', 'type']
var[2] = ['box0', 'border1', 'name']
var[3] = ['box1', 'border2', 'name']
var[4] = ['box1', 'border0', 'color']

$val = 'value'
```

In PHP the result would look like:

```
$result = array(
    'box0' => array(
      'border0' => array('name' => $val, 'type' => $val, 'color' => $val), 
      'border1' => array('name' => $val),
    ),
    'box1' => array(
      'border0' => array('color' => $val),
      'border2' => array('name' => $val)
    )
) );
```

Comment: Is this strictly for the case of 3-tuples of key, subkey, and value, or are you trying to generalize this to lists of length N?

Comment: related: [Python: Change values in dict of nested dicts using items in a list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11918852/python-change-values-in-dict-of-nested-dicts-using-items-in-a-list)

Comment: It is possible to N-tuples of key. This is only an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP answer constructs a dictionary from a *path* of keys. So here's an equivalent in Python:

```
from collections import defaultdict
def set_with_path(d, path, val):
    end = path.pop()
    for k in path:
        d = d.setdefault(k, {})
    d[end] = val
```

Example:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> set_with_path(d, ['one', 'two', 'three'], 'val')
>>> d
{'one': {'two': {'three': 'val'}}}
>>> set_with_path(d, ['one', 'four', 'six'], 'val2')
>>> d
{'one': {'four': {'six': 'val2'}, 'two': {'three': 'val'}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = dict()
for list in (a,b):
    if not x.has_key(list[0]):
        x[list[0]] = []
    x[list[0]] += list[1:]
```

Comment: That will produce `{'one': ['two', 'three', 'four', 'six']}` instead.

Comment: The phrasing of the question let me to believe he wanted a dictionary of lists.