# mongodb: update nested document by an array?

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, nested, upsert

I have a deeply nested PHP array which I saved as a document in Mongo and ended up with this structure:

```
{ 
"_id" : "...", 
"categ1" : { 
    "aaa" : 112.6736, 
    "bbb" : 83.9137, 
    "ccc" : 80.3322,
     .....
    }, 
"categ2" : { 
    "xxx" : 1, 
    "yyy" : 22, 
    "zzz" : 7,
    "subcateg" : {
         "sub1" : 1,
         "sub2" : 22
         }
    } 
}
```

Now, I have another array with a similar structure and I would like to increase the values of the record, by the values of the modifier array:

```
$modifier=array(
    'categ1' => array(
          'aaa' => 3,
          'bbb' => -1,
          'mmm' => 11
        ),
     'categ2' => array(
           'yyy' => -2,
           'subcateg' => array(
                 'sub1' => -1
            )
        )
     );
```

How can I increase the values inside the document by the values of the $modifier *all at once*, **in a single query**, and *without loading the entire document* ?

I've looked around the web but couldn't find any info on this. 
Also, i'm pretty newbie at Mongo. Thanks

Comment: What you meant by increase the values of the record? Did you mean replace by modifier

Comment: what i mean is: i need to increase the values of aaa, bbb, xxx by those specified in modifier[aaa,bbb....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your `$modifier` array to look like this:

```
$modifier = array(
  'categ1.aaa' => 3,
  'categ1.bbb' => -1,
  'categ1.mmm' => 11,
  'categ2.yyy' => -2,
  'categ2.subcateg.sub1' => -1
)
```

[Link for how to get that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424335/php-convert-multidimensional-array-to-2d-array-with-dot-notation-keys)

Then you should be able to simply use:

```
$col->update(
    array("_id" => "..."),
    array('$inc' => $modifier),
    array("upsert" => true)
);
```