# array_walk_recursive to return array name rather than index number

Tags: php, arrays, array-walk

is there a way for the array_Walk_recursive to return the name of the array instead of index?

```
function flatten(array $array) {
    $return = array();
    array_walk_recursive($array, function($a) use (&$return) { $return[] = $a; });
    return $return;
}
```

my result is something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 888
    [1] => TY7452
    [2] => 63214
    [3] => 0
    [4] => Upper
)
```

i hope can change the indexes to the array name like the first one should be Name then second should be number. And guys one more question is after i able to project out the name, is it possible for me to use implode to some sort of like set a path of the array name which will replace the index number that im currently getting? eg, car.model.number

my array

```
$trading = [
    'id' => 888,
    'case_number' => 'KO2017-987',
    'property' => [
        'id' => 78563,
        'propertyType' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Residential'
        ],
        'address' => [
            'block' => '85',
            'street' => 'Jalan Serjana',
            'subpremise' => '#07-05',
            'building' => 'TM Block',
            'country_code' => 'MY'
        ],
        'askingPrice' => '650000.00',
        'photos' => [
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/1k985k63-652b-4dpc-988b-b98f75364db0.jpg',
                'is_default' => 1
            ],
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/8cf78fb6-9545-4f5f-8dfc-235a57a2b8c1.jpg',
                'is_default' => 0
            ],
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/e456218f-8b22-4250-9b29-72c1d3f5dc45.jpg',
                'is_default' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
];
```

Desired Result

Array

```
(
    [id] => 888
    [case_number] => KO2017-987
    [property.id] => 78563
    [property.propertyType.id] => 1
    [property.propertyType.name] => Residential
    [property.address.block] => 85
    [property.address.street] => Jalan Serjana
    [property.address.subpremise] => #07-05
    [property.address,building] => TM Block
    [property.address.country_code] => MY
    [property.askingPrice] => 6500000.00
    [property.photos.0.url] =>  https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/1k985k63-652b-4dpc-988b-b98f75364db0.jpg
    [property.photos.o.is_default] => 1
    [property.photos.1.url] => https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/8cf78fb6-9545-4f5f-8dfc-235a57a2b8c1.jpg
    [property.photos.1.is_default] => 0
    [property.photos.2.url] => https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/e456218f-8b22-4250-9b29-72c1d3f5dc45.jpg
    [property.photos.2.is_default] => 0
)
```

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand. What is an "array name"? Can you give an example of an array you want to pass to `flatten` and the result you want?

Comment: ^input array and desired output array required

Comment: okay something like this

[
$trading = [
'id' => ,
'case_number' => 'TX2015-0123',
'property' => [
'id' => 69134,
'propertyType' => [
'id' => 1,
'name' => 'Residential'
]
]
];

Comment: Alright, I gave up and voted to close. If you try again, please include an actual running example in your question, including data. Then give the exact result you want to get.

Comment: (The array you shared isn't valid PHP syntax, and it doesn't tell us what you want.)

Comment: hi there sorry i have included my array

Comment: And... what do you want to do? What result do you want?

Comment: the result i wanted is like this

Array
(
    [id] => 888
    [case_number] => KO2017-987
    [property.id] => 78563
    [property.propertyType.id] => 1
    [property.propertyType.name] => Residential
)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Convert multidimensional array to 2D array with dot notation keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424335/php-convert-multidimensional-array-to-2d-array-with-dot-notation-keys)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
function flatten(array $array, $prefix="") {
    $result = Array();
    array_walk($array, function ($value, $key) use ($array, $prefix, &$result) {
        $path = $prefix ? "$prefix.$key" : $key;
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $result = array_merge($result, flatten($value, $path));
        } else {
            $result[$path] = $value;
        }
    });

    return $result;
}

$trading = [
    'id' => 888,
    'case_number' => 'KO2017-987',
    'property' => [
        'id' => 78563,
        'propertyType' => [
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Residential'
        ],
        'address' => [
            'block' => '85',
            'street' => 'Jalan Serjana',
            'subpremise' => '#07-05',
            'building' => 'TM Block',
            'country_code' => 'MY'
        ],
        'askingPrice' => '650000.00',
        'photos' => [
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/1k985k63-652b-4dpc-988b-b98f75364db0.jpg',
                'is_default' => 1
            ],
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/8cf78fb6-9545-4f5f-8dfc-235a57a2b8c1.jpg',
                'is_default' => 0
            ],
            [
                'url' => 'https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/e456218f-8b22-4250-9b29-72c1d3f5dc45.jpg',
                'is_default' => 0
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

print_r(flatten($trading));

// Output:

// Array
// (
//     [id] => 888
//     [case_number] => KO2017-987
//     [property.id] => 78563
//     [property.propertyType.id] => 1
//     [property.propertyType.name] => Residential
//     [property.address.block] => 85
//     [property.address.street] => Jalan Serjana
//     [property.address.subpremise] => #07-05
//     [property.address.building] => TM Block
//     [property.address.country_code] => MY
//     [property.askingPrice] => 650000.00
//     [property.photos.0.url] => https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/1k985k63-652b-4dpc-988b-b98f75364db0.jpg
//     [property.photos.0.is_default] => 1
//     [property.photos.1.url] => https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/8cf78fb6-9545-4f5f-8dfc-235a57a2b8c1.jpg
//     [property.photos.1.is_default] => 0
//     [property.photos.2.url] => https://www.jokok.com/thumbnails/600x400F/e456218f-8b22-4250-9b29-72c1d3f5dc45.jpg
//     [property.photos.2.is_default] => 0
// )
```