# Concatenate recursive key of an array php

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, key, concatenation

I have an array like this :

```
array(2) {

  ["xxx"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["yyy"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["text"]=> string(13) "test offline2"
        }
      ["yyy2"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["text"]=> string(12) "test offline"
        }
    }
    ["usual_name"]=> string(12) "test offline"

}
```

And I would like to have a new array like this :

```
array(3) {
  ["xxx.yyy"]=> string(12) "test offline"
  ["xxx.yyy2"]=> string(12) "test offline"
  ["usual_name"]=> string(12) "test offline"
}
```

If someone can help me pls !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP - Convert multidimensional array to 2D array with dot notation keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10424335/php-convert-multidimensional-array-to-2d-array-with-dot-notation-keys)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$arr1 = array("xxx"=>array(
                        "yyy" => array("text" => "test offline2"),
                        "yyy2" => array("text"=> "test offline")
                    ),
              "usual_name" => "test offline"
        );

$arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $key1 => $value1) {
    if(is_array($value1)) {
        foreach ($value1 as $key2 => $value2) {
            if(is_array($value2))
            {
                foreach ($value2 as $key3 => $value3) {
                    $arr2[$key1.'.'.$key2]= $value3;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $arr2[$key1]= $value1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah ! It works, thanks ! But do you know how to do it recursively pls ? (if there are more than 2/3 arrays)

Comment: `
$arr1 = array("xxx"=>array(
      "yyy" => array("text" => "test offline2"),
      "yyy2" => array("text"=> "test offline")
     ),
        "usual_name" => "test offline"
     );

$concatArray = keyConcatinate($arr1);

function keyConcatinate($arr1, $arr2 = array(), $key2 = '') {
    foreach ($arr1 as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $arr2 = array_merge($arr2, keyConcatinate($value, $arr2, $key2 . $key . '.'));
        } else {
            $arr2[$key2 . $key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $arr2;
}`

Comment: @Florian Try above code which do the same task but using recursion.