# Return the values of an array from a specified list of keys using dot notation in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am using Laravel 5.6. I want a function that returns only the specified key / value pairs from the given array using the dot notation.

For example:

```
$array = [
    'name' => [
        'first' => 'John', 
        'last' => 'Smith'
    ], 
    'price' => 100,
    'orders' => 10
];


$slice = someFunc($array, ['name.first', 'price']);
```

should return:

```
[
    'name' => [
        'first' => 'John'
    ],
    'price' => 100,
]
```

The closest function that does this is in Laravel that I can find is the `array_only` function:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-only

However, it does not support the dot notation (unlike some other Laravel functions).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What about `array_get`?

Comment: You could combine array_dot and array_only, e.g: `array_only(array_dot($array), ['name.first', 'price']);` and if you need it to be a single function then you could add your own helper that wraps these 2 functions.

Comment: Tryied `$array = collect($array); $array->get('name.first');` but it sends me `null`.

Comment: try this https://packagist.org/packages/adbario/php-dot-notation

Answer (score 2):

There's two options you could use off the top of my head. The first is to use `array_dot` to flatten a multi-dimensional array into a one dimensional dot notated array:

```
$flattened = array_dot([
    'name' => [
        'first' => 'John', 
        'last' => 'Smith'
    ], 
    'price' => 100,
    'orders' => 10
]);
```

This would yield the following result:

```
[
    'name.first' => 'John',
    'name.last' => 'Smith',
    'price' => 100,
    'orders' => 10,
]
```

From there you can get everything except orders using `array_except($flattened, 'orders')`. Of course, the resulting array will still be in dot notation which may not be ideal for you.

The second option I can think of is merging multiple calls to `array_get`, since it supports dot notation.

Comment: Unfortunately the first option as you said puts everything in dot notation. I would like it to be in the same format.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9635968/convert-dot-syntax-like-this-that-other-to-multi-dimensional-array-in-php