# Laravel convert input name array to dot notation

Tags: php, laravel

How do I convert an input name array to dot notation, similar to the way the validator handles keys? I'd like it to work for non-arrays as well.

For example, say I have:

```
$input_name_1 = 'city';
$input_name_2 = 'locations[address][distance]';
```

How would I convert that to:

```
$input_dot_1 = 'city';
$input_dot_2 = 'locations.address.distance';
```

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code-writing service; you're expected to make an effort to solve your own issue, and we'll assist with debugging.

Comment: Laravel have method for it. Its called array_get() and inverse method array_set(). Mode here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39118759/4771277

Comment: Not sure why all the hate on this question. It cropped up for me yesterday and unfortunately there are no helpful answers on this post yet. I have added the solution I came to as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

If we're just talking about converting the string representation, e.g. converting strings as follows...

- `'foo[1]'` -> `'foo.1'`
- `'foo[bar]'` -> `'foo.bar'`
- `'foo[bar][baz]'` -> `'foo.bar.baz'`

The following code does it just fine...

```
$string = str_replace('[', '.', $string); // Replace [ with .
$string = str_replace(']', '', $string); // Remove ]
```

NOTE: I could not find anyway to achieve this within the Laravel framework using existing Laravel classes/methods - but would love to know if there is a way.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a hint, you could remove `]` and then replace `[` with a dot:

psuedocode:

```
$input_name_2 = 'locations[address][distance]';
$halfway = removeClosingBracket($input_name_2); // locations[address[distance
$result = replaceOpeningBracektWithDot($halfway); // locations.address.distance
```