# Parse dot-delimited strings and make a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, text-parsing

I have an array that looks like this

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.name
            [value] => vda
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.backingIndex
            [value] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.rd.reqs
            [value] => 248907
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.rd.bytes
            [value] => 9842014208
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.rd.times
            [value] => 372870570891
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.wr.reqs
            [value] => 6869976
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.wr.bytes
            [value] => 50781960192
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.wr.times
            [value] => 32361608225142
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.fl.reqs
            [value] => 2471825
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.fl.times
            [value] => 936802992509
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.allocation
            [value] => 21107503104
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.capacity
            [value] => 21474836480
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.0.physical
            [value] => 21474836480
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.name
            [value] => hda
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.path
            [value] => /var/datastores/disk.1
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.backingIndex
            [value] => 30
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.rd.reqs
            [value] => 2871
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.rd.bytes
            [value] => 9677156
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.rd.times
            [value] => 620637479
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.capacity
            [value] => 374784
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [name] => block.1.physical
            [value] => 376832
        )
```

I need to get the array to look something like the following

```
[blocks] => Array
    (
  [block0] => Array
     (
     [backingIndex] => 2
     [rd.reqs] => 2480907
     [rd.bytes] => 9842014208
     [rd.times] = > 372870570891
     ............
             ) 
   [block1] => Array
     (
      [backingIndex] => 30
      [rd.reqs] => 2871
      [rd.bytes] => 9677156
      [rd.times] = > 620637479
      ............
     )
  )
```

its worth noting that the array contains alot more items and will contain items like

```
vcpu.0.state=1
  vcpu.0.time=963654400000000
  vcpu.0.wait=0
  vcpu.1.state=1
  vcpu.1.time=936409070000000
  vcpu.1.wait=0
  vcpu.2.state=1
  vcpu.2.time=943396180000000
  vcpu.2.wait=0
  vcpu.3.state=1
  vcpu.3.time=959496330000000
  vcpu.3.wait=0
```

which should create a similar subset

but some values do not have the integer index such as

```
  balloon.current=16777216
  balloon.maximum=16777216
  balloon.swap_in=0
  balloon.swap_out=0
  balloon.major_fault=262
  balloon.minor_fault=132293
  balloon.unused=16153712
  balloon.available=16396312
```

I could do this by using loops and looking for specific strings but the time and overhead does not seem worth it, I would like to be able to create a sub array based on a partial string like

`block.0.rd.reqs` -> `arrayName.index.value`

and I can not seem to get it to work without over 100 lines of code and an extremely long execution time.

This information is coming from running a Virsh domstats command.

Comment: This question was originally asked and closed on [codereview.se] for not containing working code.  `any help would be appreciated` is not a relevant part of any question in any Stack Exchange community.  Please always convey your input array data as `var_export()` or json output so that volunteers can instantly copy and use your data in a sandbox.  Please include your basic loop and attempt to parse the dot-delimited strings. I don't see any other way than looping and parsing.

Comment: I am asking simply for an alternative way of doing it besides 100+ lines of code i already have, maybe there is a function I am un-aware of or a post that i have not found that someone can point me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, I'd point you toward [Convert dot syntax like "this.that.other" to multi-dimensional array in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9635968/2943403) and hammer this question as an under-researched duplicate, but you seem to have sufficient deviation in your desired output.

Your sample input and desired output are not well expressed in your question, but if I am reverse engineering your requirements correctly, you just need to explode the name values, do some conditional preparation, then push the values into the 3-level output array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qlaZL))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['name' => $name, 'value' => $value]) {
    $parts = explode('.', $name);
    $parentKey = $parts[0] . 's';
    $childKey = implode(array_splice($parts, 0, ctype_digit($parts[1]) ? 2 : 1));
    $grandchildKey = implode('.', $parts);  // $parts was reduced by array_splice()
    if ($grandchildKey !== 'name') {
        $result[$parentKey][$childKey][$grandchildKey] = $value;
    }
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  'blocks' => 
  array (
    'block0' => 
    array (
      'backingIndex' => 2,
      'rd.reqs' => 248907,
      'rd.bytes' => 9842014208,
      'rd.times' => 372870570891,
    ),
    'block1' => 
    array (
      'backingIndex' => 30,
      'rd.reqs' => 2871,
      'rd.bytes' => 9677156,
      'rd.times' => 620637479,
    ),
    'block2' => 
    array (
      'backingIndex' => 30,
      'rd.reqs' => 2871,
      'rd.bytes' => 9677156,
      'rd.times' => 620637479,
    ),
  ),
  'vcpus' => 
  array (
    'vcpu0' => 
    array (
      'state' => 1,
      'time' => 963654400000000,
      'wait' => 0,
    ),
    'vcpu1' => 
    array (
      'state' => 1,
      'time' => 936409070000000,
      'wait' => 0,
    ),
    'vcpu2' => 
    array (
      'state' => 1,
      'time' => 943396180000000,
      'wait' => 0,
    ),
    'vcpu3' => 
    array (
      'state' => 1,
      'time' => 959496330000000,
      'wait' => 0,
    ),
  ),
  'balloons' => 
  array (
    'balloon' => 
    array (
      'current' => 16777216,
      'maximum' => 34534530,
      'swap_in' => 0,
      'swap_out' => 0,
      'major_fault' => 262,
      'minor_fault' => 132293,
      'unused' => 16153712,
      'available' => 16396312,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This worked if I sent in a specific section due to the way that the array is created I had to break it down one more time prior to running your function (which saved me a lot of overhead and code.

Answer (score 0):

**Revised my answer to support non-index and not knowing what is the key.**

Easy for the index part.
For the no index I used is_numeric to see if there is an index and treat the creation differently.

What I did is to loop correctly and use some explode... knowing that there is some kind of logic to this array in the name dot something.

So I built a version of your array, afterwards I looped through it using explode to cut the names of the of the blocks according to your need and that way I don't even need to know where am I in the loop ...:)

Take a look at how I gave the keys to the new array.

You can ofcourse disable some creation according to the names you get from the explode values.

```
<?php


$Array[] = ['name' => "block.0.name", 'value' => 'vda'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.0.backingIndex", 'value' => '2'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.0.rd.reqs", 'value' => '248907'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.0.rd.bytes", 'value' => '9842014208'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.0.rd.times", 'value' => '372870570891'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.1.name", 'value' => 'hda'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.1.backingIndex", 'value' => '30'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.1.rd.reqs", 'value' => '2871'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.1.rd.bytes", 'value' => '9677156'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.1.rd.times", 'value' => '620637479'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.2.name", 'value' => 'cda'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.2.backingIndex", 'value' => '30'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.2.rd.reqs", 'value' => '2871'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.2.rd.bytes", 'value' => '9677156'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "block.2.rd.times", 'value' => '620637479'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "balloon.current", 'value' => '16777216'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "balloon.maximum", 'value' => '34534530'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "balloon.rd.reqs", 'value' => '45645645'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "balloon.rd.bytes", 'value' => '967435345347156'];
$Array[] = ['name' => "balloon.rd.times", 'value' => '324234'];

/*echo '<pre>';
print_r($Array);*/

foreach($Array as $val){
    $sVal = explode(".",$val['name']);
    if(is_numeric($sVal[1])){

        $Val = str_replace($sVal[0].".".$sVal[1].".","",$val['name']);
        $newArray[$sVal[0].'s'][$sVal[0] . $sVal[1]][$Val] = $val['value'];
    } else {

        $Val = str_replace($sVal[0].".","",$val['name']);
        $newArray[$sVal[0].'s'][$sVal[0]][$Val] = $val['value'];
    }

}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($newArray);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [blocks] => Array
        (
            [block0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => vda
                    [backingIndex] => 2
                    [rd.reqs] => 248907
                    [rd.bytes] => 9842014208
                    [rd.times] => 372870570891
                )

            [block1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => hda
                    [backingIndex] => 30
                    [rd.reqs] => 2871
                    [rd.bytes] => 9677156
                    [rd.times] => 620637479
                )

            [block2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => cda
                    [backingIndex] => 30
                    [rd.reqs] => 2871
                    [rd.bytes] => 9677156
                    [rd.times] => 620637479
                )

        )

    [balloons] => Array
        (
            [balloon] => Array
                (
                    [current] => 16777216
                    [maximum] => 34534530
                    [rd.reqs] => 45645645
                    [rd.bytes] => 967435345347156
                    [rd.times] => 324234
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution other than going through the array and parsing the strings. I am *guessing* at the mapping between the input and the output - its not clear from your examples nor your narrative. It certainly should not need 100+ lines of code!

```
<?php

$base_pattern="/^(block)\.(\d+)\.(.*)$/";
$alt_pattern="/^(balloon)\.(.*)$/";

$out=array();
foreach($input_array[1] as $a) { 
    if (preg_match($base_pattern, $a['name'], $match)) {  
        // split base.123.something into 'base.', '123', 'something'
        // you could also use explode
        $key=$match[1] . $match[2];
    } else if (preg_match($alt_pattern, $a['name'], $match)) {
        $key=$match[1];
    } else {
        continue; // for entries which don't follow the pattern
    }
    if (!isset($out[$key])) { $out[$key] = array(); }
    $attribute=array_pop($match);
    $out[$key][$attribute]=$a['value'];
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `\d` segment needs to be optional based on the sample data at the end of the question.

Comment: I was still typing / saved as a draft!

Comment: `if (!isset($out[$key])) { $out[$key] = array(); }` is not necessary in php.  Also, please write `elseif` as one word in php.  (I would not make two `preg_match()` calls.)

Comment: Yes, 2 seperate calls to preg_match is not as efficient as it needs to be but I was aiming for transparency. Others....yes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I had to do for @mickmackusa's answer

```
function test($array){
$compiled = [];
        foreach($array as $item)
        {
                $result = [];
                foreach ($item as ['name' => $name,  'value' => $value]) {
                        $parts = explode('.', $name);
                        $parentKey = $parts[0] . 's';
                        $childKey = implode(array_splice($parts, 0, ctype_digit($parts[1]) ? 2 : 1));
                        $grandchildKey = implode('.', $parts);
                        if ($grandchildKey !== 'name') {
                        $result[$parentKey][$childKey][$grandchildKey] = $value;
                        }
                }
        array_push($compiled, $result);
        }
return $compiled;

}
```

Other than adding the extra foreach loop it worked flawlessly and reduced my lines of code by 77 lines